# Referencing an ASP.Net command button with ID instead of the index value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, indexing, code-behind

We have an ASP.Net command button in a GridView on a web form.

We are referencing the button with this coding using .Columns(index value):

```
GridViewSummary.Columns(6).Visible = False
```

Is it possible to reference that button using the ID of the button so the coding is easier to read? Maybe something like:

```
GridViewSummary.Columns("ButtonSelect").Visible = False
```

Here is some markup showing the ID of the button:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button 
                        ID="ButtonSelect" 
                        runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Select" 
                        Text="Select Schedule Item Details" />
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: **Where** exactly are you trying to access the button. Can you edit your answer to include the method where you are accessing the button?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's in a click handler of an image button of a code-behind file.